# Отображение без расширения при выборе файла в JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing

Необходимо, чтобы при выборе файла в `JFileChooser` файл отображался без расширения. Как? Может, есть способ лучше, чем наследовать `JFileChooser`?

Я использую вот этот код:

```
fc.addPropertyChangeListener(JFileChooser.SELECTED_FILE_CHANGED_PROPERTY, new PropertyChangeListener()
{

    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)
    {
        File selectedFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
        String path = selectedFile.getPath();
        path=FilenameUtils.removeExtension(path);
        fc.setSelectedFile(new File(path));       
     }
    });
```

Но в этом случае маркер выделения прыгает вверх. И JFileChooser возвращает неправильное имя файл (возвращает файл без расширения)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответили на stackoverflow.com:

```
fc = new JFileChooser() {

    @Override
    public void setSelectedFile(File file) {
        super.setSelectedFile(file);
        ((BasicFileChooserUI) getUI()).setFileName(getName(file));
    }

};
```